# Imported image not rendering in 2d animation render

Tags: rendering

I am drawing a stick figure fight scene and underneath all my drawings I imported a notebook paper image. When I render everything shows up except for the imported image.

Comment: How are you setting the image as the background? An image on Plane, Compositor or other?

Comment: Welcome, Jake. When I use an image as a background (using images as planes addon), I check "shadeless".

Comment: In object mode I pressed "shift+A" and went to "add, Image, Background"